# run process from python script , and the process shoud never stop

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm trying to run a script that run other script few times with subprocess.
I want the children processes to keep running after I close the parents terminal.
I tried some different arguments in subprocess popen but I didn't manage to do it.

```
 for i in range(number_of_processes_wanted - number_of_procees_runing):
        sleep(5)
        subprocess32.Popen(['python', 'some_python_script.py'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the parent python process is called **parent.py** you can do the following on your terminal.

```
nohup ./parent.py &
```

This way the parent (and the children) will keep running after you close the terminal.